# Quickest way to gather hundreds of questions and answers into xml file?

Tags: android, xml, file

I am making a program that has lots of brainteaser questions for android. I need to gather lots of questions into an XML file or some other format any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear - when you say 'gather', what do you mean? What is/are the source/sources of the questions?

Comment: @MisterSquonk By gather I mean like put maybe 100-200 questions into a xml format. I don't need help gathering the info I need help putting the data into an xml file that can be phrased easily.          PS. I have all the time in the world (AKA weekends because I am still a kid)

Comment: If this is something you need to pass over 3G/Wifi, I'd start looking into using JSON as XML is overly verbose for what it sounds like you're using it for.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hook up a Java object to an XML representation then take a look at [Simple XML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/). It will work on Android.

With that you could create a simple 'Question' class with a 'description' string and an 'expectedAnswer' string and go from there.